# Counting the levels of a variable in SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to determine the number of levels for a variable . For example , the variable 'sex' will have 3 levels M , F , NA. Is there a query in SQL Select statement , that will help us to determine the same ?

Also can we view the results of the levels ?

Comment: show your data with example

Comment: `select count(distinct [mycolumn]) from mytable;`?

Comment: Can you please post your tables structure, sample data and desired output?

Comment: You could also look into using `enum` type if the `sex` column really has a set number of values.

Comment: product_id product_type
7042              P
7056              P
30176 
30177 
30179 
30180 
30181               A
30182 
30183 
30184

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the 'number of levels' as  Phylogenesis already said is....

```
select count(distinct [mycolumn]) from mytable;
```

To get the counts per level....

```
select mycolumn, count(*) 
from mytable
group by mycolumn
```